# Starting a simple Jersey webapp

Tags: rest, nullpointerexception, jersey, init, servletexception

I want to start up a simple Jersey webapp. This is the error I get from Tomcat upon trying to access the resourcess.

`type Exception report`

> message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

description The server encountered an `internal error` that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

**exception**

> javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST
>   Service threw exception
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**root cause**

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.calcXmlName(PropertyInfoImpl.java:287)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.PropertyInfoImpl.calcXmlName(PropertyInfoImpl.java:262)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl.getTypes(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:96)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeElementPropertyInfoImpl.getTypes(RuntimeElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:50)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ElementPropertyInfoImpl$1.size(ElementPropertyInfoImpl.java:42)
>     java.util.AbstractList$Itr.hasNext(Unknown Source)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getClassInfo(ModelBuilder.java:139)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:49)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeModelBuilder.getClassInfo(RuntimeModelBuilder.java:41)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:189)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RegistryInfoImpl.(RegistryInfoImpl.java:63)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.addRegistry(ModelBuilder.java:232)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.ModelBuilder.getTypeInfo(ModelBuilder.java:201)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:352)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$3.run(JAXBContextImpl.java:350)
>     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:349)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.(JAXBContextImpl.java:215)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:76)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:55)
>     com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:124)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
>     javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlApplicationContextImpl.(WadlApplicationContextImpl.java:95)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.wadl.WadlFactory.init(WadlFactory.java:96)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.initWadl(RootResourceUriRules.java:169)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.(RootResourceUriRules.java:106)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1300)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:163)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:769)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
>     com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:760)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
>     com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
>     javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
>     org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>     org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>     org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)